# How to monitor memory for java thread stacks

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, monitor

While running a Java EE application on a 32 bit jvm on Solaris x86 I get an OutOfMemoryError:Cant create native thread (or something like that).
This is because the jvm does not have enough memory for the stack of the new thread as far as I understand it.

I use both JConsole and VisualVM 1.3 to monitor the application but I do not know what the "stackmemory" is called in these tools. In VisualVM I can monitor heapspace and permgen space while JConsole shows a few more memory areas. Is any of these memory areas set aside for stackmemory? I know it is not the heapspace of course but what about permgen or Non-heap (as it is called in JConsole)

Comment: Does the machine have enough swap?

Comment: $>swap -s
total: 1609736k bytes allocated + 760644k reserved = 2370380k used, 57741028k available.

I have set the heapsize to 3072m so the jvm should be able to use another 1024mb for non-heap space in theory ( a bit less in reality I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [JProfiler](http://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=Cr0Xn7gFtTN-eH4aEuQP6tpCfBvavzBGxwU70r-KLAQgAEAFQypuF1wVg5ermg7wOyAEBqgQbT9Bp5pIYeyTFJ75MNEfIeGf8oF65Hl03xbeF&sig=AGiWqtzBkGbk_OxDTGpgY2DsFnwD1HRgSg&adurl=http://www.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/overview.html).
In JProfiler you can get hints from Thread views and Thread states in the CPU profiling views. Here is [screencast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/07/thread-states-in-cpu-profiling-views.html) for same.

You can also check following to debug your issue: (referenced from link) There are a few things to do if you encounter this exception.

- Use the lsof -p PID command (Unix
  platforms) to see how many threads
  are active for this process.
- Determine if there is a maximum
  number of threads per process defined
  by the operating system. If the limit
  is too low for the application, try
  raising the per-process thread limit.
- Examine the application code to
  determine if there is code that is
  creating threads or connections (such
  as LDAP connections) and not
  destroying them. You could dump the
  Java threads to see if there are an
  excessive number has been created.
- If you find that too many connections
  are opened by the application, make
  sure that any thread that the
  application creates is destroyed. An
  enterprise application (.ear) or Web
  application (.war) runs under a
  long-running JVM. Just because the
  application is finished does not mean
  that the JVM process ends. It is
  imperative that an application free
  any resources that it allocates.
  Another solution would be for the
  application to use a thread pool to
  manage the threads needed.

Some part of your code may be creating lot of Threads.

Try using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) (thread pooling) in your code to limit threads in your application, And tune your threadpool size accordingly for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate it by multiplying maximum number of thread your application generates with 1024 bytes.
1024 bytes is the default stack size of a java thread, and can be changed with the Xss JVM parameter.

To avoid native memory OOM, you can reduce JVM memory usage by reducing Java Heap (and make room for native memory allocation) or reducing the Java stack size if it can be reduced.
However, if thread number of your application growth indefinitely, you have to limit it using a pool executor.